# How to prevent status bar from covering modal page in nativescript

Tags: android, telerik, nativescript

i'm having an issue with my nativescript app
The content of the modal page is pushed behind the status-bar and the status-bar covers it.
I've worked with nativescript on a previous project and i didn't have this issue with my modal pages.

I have downloaded and implemented these plugins but it had no effect

[Nativescript-status-bar](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-plugin-statusbar/)

[Natvescript-statusbar](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-statusbar/)

This is how it currently appears

[image: This is how it currently appears]

Comment: are you using Android API 23

Comment: @VikasAcharya Yes, i tested on Android 6 and Android 5, the issue occured in both. but on Android 4.3, it doesn't, android 4.3 doesn't show statusbar anyway so maybe thats why it worked there.

Comment: There is a open issue of this which is not yet fixed. Kindly have a look at it in nativescript github issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing this `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` from `App_resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

you can also check `App_resources/Android/src/main/res/values21/styles.xml` to be sure its not there also